# How can I optimize remote d/b access?

Tags: profiling, query-optimization, valgrind

I doubt that the problem is with "remote", and think it more likely to be with "d/b access" - but, how can I know?

Can/should I optimze my actual d/b structure? maybe adding foreign keys, etc

Or use a round robin d/b to limit the number of records? Or move some rows "offline" on a regular basis?

Maybe I can optimize my SQL (use of inner/outer join, etc)?

Fwiw, the norm is d/b write, which is complained of as being "too slow"; there are very few reads (just one of those cases where you store data "just in case it is needed")

Any advice, web-sites, books? Are there any [ValGrind](http://valgrind.org/)-type tools to measure/profile what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head . . .

- **Measure performance**. How long
  does it actually take, and what
  does your application do during that
  time? Use a stopwatch if you don't
  have any other way.
- **Compare local performance**. How long
  does the same task take when you access the database locally?
- **Which remote access technology** are you using?
  HTTP, VPN, VNC, ssh?
- **Which dbms** are you using?
- **What tables** are involved? Post their
  **structure** and **number of rows**.
- How does your application write to
  the database? Through **direct table access**, or
  **stored procedures**?
- **Insert** or **update**?
- Adding foreign keys is not an
  optimization. **Foreign keys are
  fundamental** to data integrity. Add them before you get fired.
- What **server-side software** are you using? Are you using php, ruby
  on rails, Django, ASP? What facilities do they offer to log their performance?

Comment: @Mawg: There might be a couple of things you can do to profile Access database activity. It depends on what the VB program is doing. Google "jet showplan" and "jet isamstats". ("Jet" is the name of the database engine that Access uses.) What does "Tables are 66 fields..." mean? Multiple 66-column tables? What normal form? Have the inserts always been "slow", or is that a new thing? Ever compact the database?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip. Sorry, 66 was a typo - I meant 6.  I think that what is happening is that over time as the databse grew it slowed, and now "it is a prolbem:. No real details, so I will have to start from scratch.